# Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing Error in django

Tags: django, image, cors, same-origin-policy

I was struggling with CORS lately in my django project. I followed all needed steps like installing django-cors-headers and here is my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework', # dasti ezafe shod
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
     'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'carat', # dasti ezafe shod
    'data',
    'price',
    'users',
    'marketplace'
]
```

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'https://example.com',
    'https://web.example.com',
)
```

We build flutter web app and deployed in web.mydomain.com. from the beginning I faced with CORS errors but once I input those settings they all disappeared except one error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/media/images/image0_WEEP09I.png. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.
I see this error in console tab of the inspector in firefox.

Here is a part of my server response:

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept, origin,Accept-Encoding
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://web.example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Length: 1884
Date: Sat, 03 Feb 2024 22:01:07 GMT
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000, quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,46
```

`
I am really confused, anyone can guide me how to fix it?

I added this code:

```
def options(self, request):
        response = Response()
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "https://example.com"
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET, OPTIONS"
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "authorization"
        return response
```

in my class to support options request.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a list of origins and not a tuple . also **CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST  is deprecated** and you should use **CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS** like below :

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://example.com',
    'https://web.example.com',
]
```

Comment: I tried once and did not go well. Ain't that due to the reason which says django does not handle requests to get static media files and it's the web server like apache, nginx or etc sends that kind of files to the front? 
That's why when you set all CORS setting in the settings.py it does not work in the response of media files.
Now I managed needed settings in .htaccess and it's going well.